# rails generates wrong 'show' route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

i have following show function:

```
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

my routes.rb looks like this:

```
resource :articles
```

but when i run `rake routes`, i get this output:

```
     articles POST   /articles(.:format)      articles#create
 new_articles GET    /articles/new(.:format)  articles#new
edit_articles GET    /articles/edit(.:format) articles#edit
              GET    /articles(.:format)      articles#show
              PATCH  /articles(.:format)      articles#update
              PUT    /articles(.:format)      articles#update
              DELETE /articles(.:format)      articles#destroy
         root GET    /
```

as you can see the articles#show route is wrong because an `:id` is needed to show a single article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resource :articles
```

should be

```
resources :articles
```

But you have discovered what `resource` method does :)